# Put Datetime picker(Bootstrap) in my header

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two DateTimePicker and I want to put them in my header. I'm really lost and I can not find anything to put them in the right place.

The template is from Bootstrap web site.

I added my DateTime Picker part to it, but not in the desired place. I need some help or advice.

**From this :** 
[image]
**To this :**
[image: ![enter image description here]
**Desired place :**
[image]

**Code added:**

```
div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form id="frm1">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Start Date</span>
                <input type="text" id='searchStartDate' name="searchStartDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Search start date" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"/>
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3">End Date</span>
                <input type="text" id='searchEndDate' name="searchEndDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Search end date" aria-describedby="basic-addon3"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>  
</div>
```

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */ 
    .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
    }

    /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust as needed) */
    .row.content {height: 550px}

    /* Set gray background color and 100% height */
    .sidenav {
      padding-top: 20px;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      height: 100%;
    }

    /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
    footer {
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px;
    }

    /* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid */
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .sidenav {
        height: auto;
        padding: 15px;
      }
      .row.content {height:auto;} 
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <form id="frm1">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Start Date</span>
                <input type="text" id='searchStartDate' name="searchStartDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Search start date" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"/>
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3">End Date</span>
                <input type="text" id='searchEndDate' name="searchEndDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Search end date" aria-describedby="basic-addon3"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>  
</div>    
<div class="container-fluid text-center">    
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 text-left"> 
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <h3>Test</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
  <p>Footer Text</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */ 
    .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
    }

    /* Set height of the grid so .sidenav can be 100% (adjust as needed) */
    .row.content {height: 550px}

    /* Set gray background color and 100% height */
    .sidenav {
      padding-top: 20px;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
      height: 100%;
    }

    /* Set black background color, white text and some padding */
    footer {
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px;
    }

    /* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid */
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .sidenav {
        height: auto;
        padding: 15px;
      }
      .row.content {height:auto;} 
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>

      <form id="frm1" class="navbar-form navbar-left">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Start Date</span>
                <input type="text" id='searchStartDate' name="searchStartDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Search start date" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"/>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3">End Date</span>
                <input type="text" id='searchEndDate' name="searchEndDate" class="form-control" placeholder="Search end date" aria-describedby="basic-addon3"/>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>



<div class="container-fluid text-center">    
  <div class="row content">
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
      <p><a href="#">Link</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 text-left"> 
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      <h3>Test</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
      <div class="well">
        <p>ADS</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="container-fluid text-center">
  <p>Footer Text</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I searched for like 3 hours, I hope some days I became good with Bootstrap and what if I want some space between them, How to do that?

Comment: I've added input-group class. Can you check again?